# EF Core One to One - result is returned only for one record

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am facing this problem for a several hours, could someone take a look what I am doing wrong?

Relationship One to One returns value only for one record, if there would be three Products with idCategory = 2 only one of them will have a Category. I have even tried using CategoryId instead of idCategory, still does not work.

Using EF Core 3.1.5 and .NET Core 3.1, downgrading versions do not work as well.

In Product class:

```
public int idCategory { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("idCategory")]
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

In Category class:

```
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

Also I could not add to DB two records in Products with same idCategory so I inserted to OnModelCreating:

```
builder.Entity<Product>().HasIndex(e => e.idCategory).IsUnique(false);
```

And Fluent API:

```
builder.Entity<Category>()
.HasOne<Product>(b => b.Product)
.WithOne(i => i.Category)
.HasForeignKey<Product>(b => b.idCategory);
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("products")]
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    return products.GetProducts();
}
```

In ProductRepository:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    return context.Products.Include(x => x.Category)
        .Where(x => x.Category.IsActive == true && x.IsActive == true).ToList();
}
```

In ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

Result:
[JSON Result - Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veXzy.png)

^ Same thing happends with lazy loading, but then 1st record has a value for category, and 2nd not

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure isn't One to Many relationship ?
If I understand correctly you just want return the category of a product, why didn't you add this property "CategoryId" in class "Product" and create a other class "Categories" with all Categories.
Something like this :

**Class Product**

```
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
public Categories CategoryId { get; set; }
```

**Class Categories**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public ICollection<Product> Product {get; set;}
```

Like this you'll can add a category for each products recorded.

You can check the ASP Net Core 3.1 documentation about Access Data :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Yea, it was my fault, changing in Category class "public virtual Product Product { get; set; }" to "public virtual ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }" solved problem. Thank you Lucas :)